# iPhone - creating a define for a NSSortDescriptor... is that possible?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, ipad

I use this a lot

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:nil 
                       ascending:YES 
                       comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
                       return [obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSNumericSearch];
                       }];
```

I would like to create a compiler define like this

```
#define descriptor [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:nil 
                       ascending:YES 
                       comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
                       return [obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSNumericSearch];
                      }]
```

so I can use it on all parts of my code without having to declare it all times and use it on stuff like

```
mySortedArray = [myArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]];
```

. I have tried this and received a ton of errors from Xcode. Is there a way to define that?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
#define descriptor [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:nil \
                                                 ascending:YES \
                                                comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) { \
                                      return [obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSNumericSearch];}]
```

Then:

```
NSArray *sorted = [myArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]];
```

The reason you get errors is because you should use **\** when going to a new line. Also `-sortedArrayUsingDescriptors` requires an array...

Answer (score 1):

You can create one of two things:

1. A category for your `NSObjects` and there you could define your method.
2. An util class with a class method that would do what you want.

Depending of your use for your `NSSortDescriptor` a category could be a good solution. You can always put it to be a `NSArray`'s category instead of a `NSObject` one.

Answer (score 1):

The reason what i see for it not to work is that the function 
`[NSArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:];`

requires an **array** as a parameter, however you are passing a `NSSortDescriptor` directly.

Try using the same as:

```
myArray = [myArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]];
```

The `#define` will be

```
#define descriptor [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:nil \
                       ascending:YES \
                       comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) { \
                       return [obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSNumericSearch]; \
                      }]
```

**OR**

```
#define descriptor [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:nil ascending:YES comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) { return [obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSNumericSearch]; }]
```